# What does "cazzuccio" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, translation, swearwords

I am reading Zerocalcare, and I am stuck at this word.

http://www.zerocalcare.it/2018/10/09/quando-i-vecchi-salgono-nella-tua-macchina/

Third picture from top, the male character responds to his mother's comment on how dirty his car is, by saying:

> "La macchina è mia e la tengo come cazzuccio mi pare a me, va bene?".

What does this mean? I am guessing "cazzuccio" is a rude word, but I can't find it anywhere. I have tried the Collins dictionary, the Oxford dictionary, and Wiktionary.

Comment: It's a diminutive of "cazzo" with a pejorative nuance. See this [Treccani dictionary entry](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/uccio).

Comment: @Charo I wouldn't say "pejorative", it strikes me as more of a "vezzeggiativo" ("endearing")

Comment: So what does the whole sentence mean then? "The car is mine and I keep it like shi* looks to me"? Sounds a bit strange.

Comment: @DenisNardin:  I'm not mother tongue Italian, so it's likely the way you say (this why I wrote a comment and not an answer).

Comment: I really admire your boldness in reading Zerocalcare as a non-native speaker.

Comment: Thanks @LSerni, I've got tired of courses and easy readers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard Italian sentence (low, colloquial register) would be

> La macchina è mia e la tengo come [cazzo] mi pare a me, va bene?
>
> The car is mine, and I keep it (how I [fucking] like / how [the fuck] I want), is that fine?

As noted in the comments and in the other answer, *cazzo* is used as a generic expletive, like *fucking* in English. It is idiomatic to add it without prepositions after *come* or other interrogative pronouns, exactly like *the fuck* is used in English.

Note that another expression that is grammatically incorrect in textbook Italian but common in the low/popular register is *mi pare a me*: grammar rules would dictate that either *mi* or *a me* is used, but not both.

The 'endearing' version *cazzuccio* is non-standard usage; the author used it as a literary device for comic effect here. He is mixing registers for comic effect: those sentences pair a fake exaggeratedly polite / endearing tone with a couple of very vulgar / impolite expressions to invite her not to bother him. See also *cariiisssima madriiisssima* earlier, where the same fake polite tone is used. Literally it means *my dearest motherest*: *madrissima* is another made-up word, where a superlative ending is added to a noun instead of to an adjective. The supernumerary repeating *i*'s and  *s*'s are used to show in writing that these words are spoken out slowly, to add emphasis.

Overall this is a very difficult text to read for a non-native speaker. The author uses literary devices, made-up or uncommon words, expressions from the youth slang and Roman dialect, popular culture references.

Answer (score 7):

The term ***cazzuccio*** is an endearing (as correctly specified by @Denis Nardin) term of cazzo, which is a rude word.

The literal meaning of cazzo is a vulgar term for “penis” (“cock” say), but it is used as a kind of universal expletive, not dissimilar from “fuck” (and “fucking” etc. ) in English.

It also means that the person who’s speaking has some confidence with the other person and doesn’t want to hurt his or her feelings.

And yes, the sentence just mean:

> The car is mine and I keep it like sh*t looks to me. (Don’t bother me with your rants.)

Moreover, about the suffix -[uccio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/uccio/) (as suggested by @Charo):

> **-ùccio** [lat. -ūceus] (f. -ùccia; f. pl. -ucce). – 1. Suffisso che serve a formare sostantivi e aggettivi alterati con valore diminutivo,
>   di tono ora vezzeggiativo ora, e più spesso, spregiativo: tesoruccio,
>   casuccia, guadagnuccio, gentuccia (gente meschina), robuccia (roba
>   scadente), ecc. 2. Come agg., nel linguaggio fam., misero, scadente:
>   un affaruccio uccio uccio; questo vestito si è fatto un po’ uccio, si
>   è un po’ logorato.

Comment: I'd say that a more idiomatic translation is "... I keep it how I f**king  like" (here I read "pare" as an expression of preference)

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, "cazzo" is a very rude word, similar to the English "fucking" (saying "la tengo come cazzo mi pare" would be something similar to "I keep it how I fucking like"). But, by saying "cazzuccio" the speaker wants to smooth out the word so as not to seem so rude.

Comment: @Charo Precisely

Comment: Just to complete the explanation, the literal meaning of _cazzo_ is a vulgar term for “penis” (“cock”, say), but it is used as a kind of universal expletive, not dissimilar from “fuck” (and “fucking” etc.) in English.

Comment: @DaG If you don’t mind I would like to add your comment to my answer

Comment: @abarisone: Be my guest!

Answer (score 6):

*Cazzuccio* is, indeed, the "endearing" form of *cazzo* (by adding the endearing suffix -uccio), used as an emphatic and also to somewhat reduce the aggressivity of the response, since the author is speaking to his mother.

The opposite effect would have been obtained with an augmentative prefix - "La macchina la tengo come *stracazzo* mi pare".

It translates well enough to "I'll keep my car like I *jolly fucking* want", at least in British English, as the "rude" form of *jolly well*:

> informal•British 
>       used for emphasis, especially when one is angry or irritated.
>       "I'm going to keep on eating as much sugar as I jolly well like"

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jolly-well)

Charo is correct, however, in saying that it normally would have a pejorative meaning - that's because the endearing terms (at least in Italian) usually also imply a smaller size, power, or duration than average: *tesoruccio* is a *little treasure*, endearing when it's a child, but obviously disappointing when it's loot.

Comment: Which is the source of your citation?

Comment: @Charo sorry! I apparently ate that line when pasting.